# Objective-C String Format by keyword

Tags: python, objective-c

In Objective C, is there a way to format a string similar to [python's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) `str.format` method. I would like to be able to take a string with keywords `@"this is {keyword_1}, and this is {keyword_2}"` and replace those keywords using some dictionary `@{@"keyword_2": @"bar", @"keyword_1": @"foo"}`, resulting in a new string `@"this is foo, and this is bar"`.

In Objective C, this might look like:

```
[NSString stringWithKeywordFormat:@"hello {user_name}, today is {day_of_week}!" keywords:@{@"user_name":@"Jack", @"day_of_week":@"Thursday"}];
```

Comment: There's nothing like that built-in. The [GRMustache](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache) template library seems to implement something similar though (never used it myself).

Comment: @omz. Thanks for the pointer. I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy to write such a function, using the `NSScanner` class to parse the format string.

Declare a category on `NSString` in a .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (KeywordFormat)
+ (NSString *)stringWithKeywordFormat:(NSString *)format keywords:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end
```

The implementation in the .m file looks like this

```
#import "NSString+KeywordFormat.h"

@implementation NSString (KeywordFormat)

+ (NSString *)stringWithKeywordFormat:(NSString *)format keywords:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:format];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];

    NSString *temp;
    while ( ![scanner isAtEnd] )
    {
        // copy characters to the result string until a { is found
        if ( [scanner scanUpToString:@"{" intoString:&temp] )
            [result appendString:temp];
        if ( [scanner isAtEnd] )
            break;

        // swallow the { character
        if ( ![scanner scanString:@"{" intoString:NULL] )
            break;
        if ( [scanner isAtEnd] )
            break;

        // get the keyword
        if ( ![scanner scanUpToString:@"}" intoString:&temp] )
            break;
        if ( [scanner isAtEnd] )
            break;

        // swallow the } character
        if ( ![scanner scanString:@"}" intoString:NULL] )
            break;

        // lookup the keyword in the dictionary, and output the value
        [result appendFormat:@"%@", dictionary[temp]];
    }

    return( [result copy] );
}

@end
```

Comment: There should probably be a way to have a literal `{` in the string that doesn't represent the start of a variable.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed. I decided to leave that part as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the standard first-party Apple libraries, no. I've never seen anything in a third-party library, either.